# How can I extract the first parameter from Intent?

Tags: java, android

I want to extract the first parameter from Intent method. How could I do that?

example, BroadcastCodes.LOGIN_BROADCAST is only string parameter.

```
Utilities.sendLocalBroadcastActivity(new Intent(BroadcastCodes.LOGIN_BROADCAST, null,
                  ServerConnectionManager.this, LoginActivity.class));
```

In the MainActivity class will be:

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    progressInfo = findViewById(R.id.splash_screen_progress_info);

    Utilities.startService(this, StickyService.class);

        localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // How should I extract the first parameter to compare and call other function.

        String broadcast = intent.getStringExtra("?");

        logger.info("Received broadcast: " + broadcast);
        if(?)
        {
          handleConnectBroadcast(broadcast);
        }
      }
    };
    connectionMessagesHandler = new ConnectionMessagesHandler();
  }
```

Comment: The question is not duplicated or not efficient. Why decrease -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, you want to fetch the first param i.e `BroadcastCodes.LOGIN_BROADCAST` which is the action param,

use `intent.getAction();`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Is `getAction()` for the first parameter?

Comment: Yes. see the constructor : Intent(String action, Uri uri, Context packageContext, Class<?> cls).

Comment: If you want to pass and retrieve the extras, have to use it like @solamente answer

Answer (score 0):

Thats an example how you can extract the intent data:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String age= intent.getStringExtra("age");
String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
```

In your code it will be:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String broadcast = intent.getStringExtra("YOUR_EXTRA_NAME");
```

In your comment case you should add:

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.LOGIN_BROADCAST)){
//code
}
```

Comment: I send a `BroadcastCodes.LOGIN_BROADCAST`, which is other class with `LOGIN_BROADCAST` string parameter. How could I extract this string parameter?. Should I write "BroadCast" only?

Comment: I have many variables with BroadcastCodes, so I don't want to specify with certain one like `LOGIN_BROADCAST`. I need to read only the first String that send from the method parameter and call other method.

Comment: I think that is the only way you have to specify wich event you want to use

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ABC.this,XYZ.class);
intent.putExtra("any_key_name","any_value");
startActivity(intent)
```